# Get key word from grep coutput

Tags: bash, grep

I have an existing basic script that I need to get the value of **SERIAL** only from it whether I grep cat or dog. Like this:

```
# grep dog | <additional commands>
123456789
```

The script = animals.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

ANIMAL=$1

case "${ANIMAL}" in
        dog)
                echo ""
                echo "${ANIMAL} animal is chosen"
                SERIAL=123456789
                ;;
        cat)
                echo ""
                echo "${ANIMAL} animal is chosen"
                SERIAL=987654321
                ;;
        *)
                echo ""
                echo "wrong parameter applied"
                exit 1
                ;;
esac
```

So far I have tried these however I'm still trying to research on how to continue or trim the other outputs

```
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-100-101 ~]$ grep dog -A 3 animals.sh 
        dog)
                echo ""
                echo "${ENV} animal is chosen"
                SERIAL=123456789
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-100-101 ~]$
```

Comment: The script you provide as input seems broken; should `$ENV` also be `$ANIMAL`?

Comment: thanks for checking, I made a correction now on my post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `awk` is your option, would you please try:

```
awk '
/dog/ {f = 1}                   # if the line matches "dog", set a flag
f && /SERIAL/ {                 # if the flag is set and the line matches "SERIAL"
    sub(".*SERIAL=", "")        # remove substring before the number
    print                       # print the result
    exit
}
' animals.sh
```

Output:

```
123456789
```

If you prefer `grep` solution, here is an alternative:

```
grep -Poz 'dog[\s\S]+?SERIAL=\K\d+' animals.sh
```

Explanation:

- The `-P` option enables `PCRE` regex.
- The `-o` option tells grep to print only the matched substring
- The `-z` option sets the record separator to the null character, enabling
  the pattern match across lines.

About the regex:

- `dog[\s\S]+?SERIAL=` matches a shortest string (including newline characters)
  between `dog` and `SERIAL=` inclusive.
- `\K` tells the regex engine to discard preceding matches out of the
  matched pattern. It works to clear the matched pattern before `\K`.
- `\d+` matches a sequence of digits which will be printed as a result.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. As you may have known the result of `grep` does not include a newline character at the end. Please append a newline depending on your requirements.

Comment: noted on it, thanks tshiono for your effective solution